# Is there any Container for playing MJPEG and MP3 as video?

Tags: mp3, format, jpeg, containers, codec

So I have MP3 track and MJPEG Is there any container for combining those 2 and playing them as one video track in one container?

Answer (score 0):

You can mix them into an AVI